# Reducing code length for programming of XML Files (Python)

Tags: python

Good day all,

I have created a Python script to change the attribute value of the XML file. However, I am seeking an alternative to code without using multiple FOR loops. Attached below is the script I have written to replace a single attribute value.

```
init = "Sample"
filename = "ABCD"
tree = ET.parse(newfile)
root = tree.getroot()
        for q in root.findall("dashboards"):
            for r in q.findall("dashboard"):
                for s in r.findall("datasources"):
                    for t in s.findall("datasource"):
                        data_capt = t.get("caption")
                        if init in data_capt:
                            t.set("caption", data_capt.replace(init, filename))
```

Greatly appreciate the assistance in advance.
Thanks and best regards,

James

Comment: A recursive function can reduce the count of nested loops in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findall` method "[provides limited support for XPath expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)" as an alternative to tag names. The following should be equivalent:

```py
for t in root.findall('./dashboards/dashboard/datasources/datasource'):
    data_capt = t.get('caption')
    if init in data_capt:
        t.set('caption', data_capt.replace(init, filename))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply and answer! It works:)